# Is TensorFlow suitable for Recommendation Systems

Tags: tensorflow

I have read blogpost about TensorFlow is being open sourced.

In the tutorials and the examples on the TensorFlow website, I see that they are mostly classification problems. (e.g. given an image, classify the number written in it)

I am curious about it the software also suitable for solving problems in recommendation system?
For example, is it good for solving problems on collaborative filtering / content-based filtering?

Comment: most probably it is suitable for many things. But this sort of question is not suitable for SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tensorflow is great for deep learning, or training large neural nets. Although, it can be used for several other mathematical applications such as PDEs, various classifiers, recommendation systems etc, there doesn't seem to have a lot of support for them as yet.

This [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3aeazf/recommender_system_libraries_in_python/) might be a good place to start for searching libraries which are centred around recommendation systems.